# Rename variable name received from server?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting data from service in the following format

```
Backend- first_name
Frontend- firstName
```

yourData.ts file

```
export interface YourData {
    first_name: number;
}
```

On the UI Angular I would like to display the format to `Lower camel case`

html

```
firstName is {{firstName}}
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rename fields of an object when it is present. You have 2 options here.

**1st**

Define 3 optional fields in your interface

```
export interface YourData{
   first_name: number;
   firstName?: number;
}
```

And then you put a method in between where you just map the values.

```
convertToCamelCase(data: YourData): void {
    data.firstName= data.first_name;
}
```

The object gets processed "by reference" so you don't need to return it.

**2nd**

You build up a second interface with the names in CamelCase and then you do the mapping.

```
export interface CopyDataInterface{
      firstName: number;
}


convertToCamelCase(data: YourData): CopyDataInterface{
   // instantiate an object dupdata using the interface CopyDataInterface
   // [...]
    dupdata .firstName= data.first_name;
    return dupdata;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the value to a new field and then remove it using [delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

```
// Copy
tempData.firstName = tempData.first_name;

// Remove
delete (tempData.first_name);
```

But I recommend you modify your server to send the data in correct format rather than modifying in client side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using Postgresql database where column names contains `first_name`. Due to naming convention I want to display as `firstName` on UI. So I am not sure how can I modify server? Can you help me out

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this? For aesthetic reasons?

It's common to translate data originating from some other source (e.g. a server) into an app-specific data structure, so you could do that. Assuming JSON from your server, you'd typically have an interface to represent the parsed data:

```
interface ServerData {
  first_name: string;
  // ...other data
}
```

After you've parsed the server data you can translate it into something more useful in the UI.

```
class UiData {
    public readonly firstName: string;
    // ...other data

    constructor(data: ServerData) {
        this.firstName = data.first_name;
        // ...set other data
    }
}
```

Typically this is done to filter out extraneous data from the server response or perform translations on the data. But it's even better to do all that on the server, if at all possible.

Comment: This did not work, it says `No suitable injection token for parameter 'data' of class component name'`

Comment: Well this isn't a full code sample, it just shows how you can construct a more useful data type out of some source data type. From the error, it sounds like you're dealing with more than just a data type transformation, though, since injection tokens are typically used for dependency injection in Angular... there's no need for any dependency injection in this case. Happy to look at the full code if you post it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use destructuring and rename

```js
// Data received the backend
const response = { first_name: "hello" };

// Use destructuring and rename (alias)
const { first_name: firstName } = response;

console.log(firstName)
```

Comment: It there any way I do change the name in interface, export and then display on UI?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only for displaying purpose, you can assign it in a local variable ("firstName") on UI side and use the same. Or, add a new key ("firstName") to the JSON data and use.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have only one key in data,

```
function modifyNameKey(obj) { 
return { firstName: obj.first_name }; 
} 
modifyNameKey({first_name: 'abc'}); // {firstName: "abc"}
```